# StrongSwan and Windows 10 & IOS

Tags: linux, networking, vpn

I'm been trying to build a small VPN server for while already.

Its working well for iOS but I can't get Windows 10 to work correctly.

I'm trying to do this using PSK rather than certificates due to the number of devices that it will be used for.

The aim is to use the built in Windows VPN. I understand that Windows can't use PSK for IPSec and needs to use `eap-mschapv2` to authenticate.

What am I doing wrong? I see the Windows 10 PC attempt the connection and the following is shown in the log. But it never gets an IP on the local LAN. I have tried various configs, none work for Windows.

```
charon: 10[IKE] 99.40.248.72 is initiating an IKE_SA 
charon: 12[IKE] 99.40.248.72 is initiating a Main Mode IKE_SA  
charon: 11[IKE] 99.40.248.72 is initiating a Main Mode IKE_SA
```

The server is a Raspberry Pi; ports 50, 500, and 4500 are forwarded to the PI.

**/etc/ipsec.conf**

```
    config setup
    cachecrls=yes
    uniqueids=yes

conn ios
    keyexchange=ikev1
    authby=xauthpsk
    xauth=server
    left=%any
    leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    leftfirewall=yes
    right=%any
    #rightsourceip=192.168.1.0/24
    rightsourceip=%dhcp
    rightdns=8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
    auto=add

conn IPSec-IKEv2-EAP
    keyexchange=ikev2
    leftfirewall=yes
    leftauth=pubkey
    leftsendcert=always
    rightauth=eap-mschapv2
    rightsendcert=never
    eap_identity=%any
```

**/etc/ipsec.secrets**

```
192.168.1.248 : PSK "MyStrongSharedPSK"

user1  : XAUTH  "MyOtherPassword"
user1  : EAP    "MyOtherPassword"
user2  : XAUTH  "AnotherPasswordHere"
```

Comment: Did you already consult [the documentation](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Windows7) on the strongSwan wiki?

Comment: Hi, yes.. Its focused on using certificates. I cant seem to find a basic simple config. suing psk

Comment: That's what you should use. Don't use PSKs, in particular, if there are many clients.

Comment: I looked at using: `conn win7 
    keyexchange=ikev2
    ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024!
    esp=aes256-sha1!
    dpdaction=clear
    dpddelay=300s
    rekey=no
    left=%any
    leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    leftauth=pubkey
    leftcert=vpnCert.pem
    leftid=@vpn.strongswan.org
    right=%any
    rightsourceip=%DHCP
    rightauth=eap-mschapv2
    eap_identity=%any
    auto=add`

Comment: But not sure what to do with "VPN gateway always authenticates itself with an X.509 certificate using a strong RSA/ECDSA signature. " and "o either the md4 plugin or one of the crypto library wrappers (OpenSSL, Gcrypt) is required."